# Find an element that isn't in nontrivial supspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W_1,W_2$ and $W_3$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$ (over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) such that they satisfy the following conditions:

- $W_1,W_2$ and $W_3$ are different of $\{0\}$ and $V$.
- $W_i$ is not a subset of $W_k$, for all $i,k \in \{1,2,3\}$ with $i\neq k$.

Is possible find an element $\alpha \in V$ such that $\alpha \notin W_i$ with $i \in \{1,2,3\}$? If yes, how and is possible extend for $n$ (a finite number) subspaces?

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem. Can you tell us what you've tried, what you don't understand, and where you're stuck?

Comment: Well, I'm trying extend a result of the problems book "Linear Algebra - Challenging problems for students" of John Hopkins. The result says that is ever possible find a basis for V such that none of elements of the basis is contained in two nontrivial subspaces  of V. I'm trying extend that for three, but I can't even find an element such that it isn't contained in three nontrivial supspaces.

Comment: Is V a generic vector space or a vector space over an infinite field? Because for the plane over Z/(2) this isn't true

Comment: V is a generic vector space.

Answer (score 0):

If the base field is finite, then it isn't true: take the field $F = \mathbb Z_2$, and $V=\mathbb Z_2^2$. $W_1 = (x,0)$, $W_2 = (y,y)$, $W_3 = (0,z)$.   Every element of the $\mathbb Z_2$-plane belong to one of those three lines. But this is a bit trivial.

If the base field is $\mathbb R$, then it is true: in such a case dim$W_i <$ dim$V$, so a finite, or even a numerable number of such subspaces cannot fill the whole of $V$: just take the plane $\mathbb R^2$ and draw as many lines through the origin you like, most vectors will not belong to one of them.

Comment: The second condition imposes that $dimV \ge 3$. Sorry, I didn't understand that you are talking about of that vector space in your comment. $\mathbb Z_2$ is the complex field right?

Comment: And about the element (1,2),which line it belong?

Comment: No, $\mathbb Z_2$ is the finite field with two elements. I asked you if you meant the base field to be finite or not. So, there is no $2$ in  $\mathbb Z_2$, just  $0$ and $1$. Moreover, the second condition doesn't imply that the dimension is three or more, just take the $x$ axis, the $y$ axis and the line $y=x$ in the plane $\mathbb R^2$ and you'll see it.

Comment: Ok. You're right about the dimension. But, according with the definition of field that I know, the field can't have just two elements, because if x and y belong to a field F, then x+y belongs to F.

Comment: Yes, $1+1 = 0$  in $\mathbb Z_2$. Excuse me if I ask, but you never heard of a finite field? You are not a math student. Maybe your book/teacher was thinking about Real or Complex vector spaces: for that your exercise is trivially true.

Comment: The field is Real or Complex, sorry about that. I gonna fix the question. Thanks for the patience.